# How to replace multiple links with multiple dynamic url using jquery each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple headings with mysite.com internal links like below:

[Article 1](https://example.com/link1)

https://externalsite1.com/url1

[Article 2](https://example.com/link2)

https://externalsite2.com/url2

[Article 3](https://example.com/link3)

https://externalsite3.com/url3

I need to replace all the articles internal site links to their below external sites urls

I have tried this at here: http://jsfiddle.net/n4hwjrsq/2/
but no luck, please help me

```
$("a").each(function() {
  var external_link = $("div.ptb_original_link").text(); 
  $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace('',external_link)); 
});
```

I expect the output with externalsite links like below :

[Article 1](https://externalsite1.com/url1)

https://externalsite1.com/url1

[Article 2](https://externalsite2.com/url2)

https://externalsite2.com/url2

[Article 3](https://externalsite3.com/url3)

https://externalsite3.com/url3

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".entry_title a").each(function() {
  $(this).attr('href',$(this).closest('div').next().html()); 
});
```

Or to make sure if there might be other `div`s before the one with external link:

```
$(".entry_title a").each(function() {
  $(this).attr('href',$(this).closest('div').next('.ptb_original_link').html()); 
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv4mpzk5/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific with your `external_link` variable, otherwise you're just going to end up with every URL in every link:

```js
$("a").each(function() {
  var external_link = $(this).parent().parent().next("div.ptb_original_link").text();
  $(this).attr('href', external_link);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ptb_title">
  <h2 class="entry_title"><a href="https://example.com/link1">Article 1</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="ptb_original_link">https://externalsite1.com/url1</div>
<br>
<div class="ptb_title">
  <h2 class="entry_title"><a href="https://example.com/link2">Article 2</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="ptb_original_link">https://externalsite2.com/url2</div>
<br>
<div class="ptb_title">
  <h2 class="entry_title"><a href="https://example.com/link3">Article 3</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="ptb_original_link">https://externalsite3.com/url3</div>
<br>
```